# How do I pass a user input as an argument into a function prototype?

Tags: c++, function, parameters, arguments, prototype

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int nCount = 0, nX = 0;
double sum_total, nAverage;
// Function Prototypes

int Sum(int number);                        // Returns the sum of two ints
int Max(int i, int j);                          // Returns max of two ints
int Min(int i, int j);                          // Returns min of two ints
double Average(int nCount, int sum_total);  // Returns the avg - (sum_total/count)

int main(){
    cout << "How many numbers would you like to enter?" << endl;
    cin >> nCount;
    cout << "You would like to enter " << nCount << " numbers\n";

    while (nX < nCount)
    {
        int a;
        cout << "Please enter you numbers: "; // Pass this value into functions
        cin >> a;
        // Call Sum, Max, Min, and Average passing these two arguments
        int Sum(a);
        nX++;
    }
    cout << "The total is: " << sum_total << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

int Sum(int number)
{
    sum_total = number + number;
    return sum_total;
}
```

This is the program I am working on. What I would like to do is have the user enter any number of integers using cin and then pass that value into the function int Sum to add all the numbers together and then display the sum of them. The while loop allows the user to enter how ever many numbers they would like, and then that argument is passed into the next function. This program however will return 0 as the sum. What is the reason for 0 being displayed? And what do I need to do in order to make this program work?

**EDIT**

```
int Max(int number)
{
    if (number > currentMax)
        currentMax = number;
    return currentMax;
}

//

int Min(int number)
{
    if (currentMin < number)
        currentMin = number;
    return currentMin;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function call is invalid. You should call it like so:

```
Sum(a);
```

Also, because sum_total is a global variable, you don't need to return a value from Sum.

**EDIT**

Here is the appropriate Sum() definition as well:

```
void Sum(int number)
{
    sum_total += number;
}
```

Note: don't forget to initialize sum_total to 0.

Comment: Okay, I understand that. So I went ahead and made the change to the function call, and entered to use 2 numbers. I chose 2, then wanted to add 1 and 2 and the program returned 4 as the sum total when it should return 3...

Comment: Sum() should add the number to the sum, not the number x2 to the sum. See edit.

Comment: Yes! I had just done this myself and it worked. I cannot believe I did not see that error. Thank you very much.

Comment: Now, if I wanted to make another function that would sort through the list of inputted numbers and find the max and min values, I know I need to do something such as 

CurrentMaximum = Max(CurrentMaximum, NumberJustInputed);
CurrentMinimum = Min(CurrentMinimum, NumberJustInputed);

Where the current max and min value is automatically set to the first number entered and then tested against the next value entered. Should I create a variable called currentmax and currentmin and assign them to 0?

Comment: Thanks again for all the help. I created two functions for max and min, and max works however min does not work. I set up an if statement saying if the number inputted is greater than the current max, the current max = number inputted. As for min, I have the same setup but with the comparison switched, yet this returns 0. Could you tell me why?

Comment: I cannot guess what you did. I need the code in order to see what's wrong.

Comment: By the way, always specify the edited sections in your text with an EDIT statement/flag of your choice to inform the readers that the section you added was not in your original post.

Comment: Your if statement is wrong. You should test if number < currentMin and not the opposite.

Comment: Okay. That makes plenty sense. However, if I do so, would the program not always return 0? Because the user input is always being compared with 0, and if the user enters no number less than 0, the currentMin will not change. I could just make the currentMin assigned to 32767.

Comment: That's why you need to initialize currentMin to a highest value (like 1000000) or to the first value you input (prefered).